# A RenderFlex overflowed by 12 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

The error is caused even in expanded widget, if I try to add scroll view then my whole screen get empty, possibly due to more number of widgets.

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Row(

          children: [

            Expanded(
              child: ReusableCard(
                onPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedGender = Gender.male;
                  });
                },
                colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
                    ? kActiveCardColor
                    : kInactiveCardColor,
                cardChild: ReusableCardData(
                  cardIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                  cardText: 'Male',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // SizedBox(
            //   width: 15,
            // ),
            Expanded(
              child: ReusableCard(
                onPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedGender = Gender.female;
                  });
                },
                colour: selectedGender == Gender.female
                    ? kActiveCardColor
                    : kInactiveCardColor,
                cardChild: ReusableCardData(
                  cardIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                  cardText: 'Female',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

The image included is the error in the UI. please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ReusableCard(
          onPress: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedGender = Gender.male;
            });
          },
          colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
            ? kActiveCardColor
            : kInactiveCardColor,
          cardChild: ReusableCardData(
            cardIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
            cardText: 'Male',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ReusableCard(
          onPress: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedGender = Gender.female;
            });
          },
          colour: selectedGender == Gender.female
            ? kActiveCardColor
            : kInactiveCardColor,
          cardChild: ReusableCardData(
            cardIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
            cardText: 'Female',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
)
```

You can try this.